# ASP.NET Web Service and Membership

Tags: asp.net, service, membership

I try use Membership in asmx web service. I use Web Site Administration Tool, create som roles and users.

In asmx web service I create Login method a test some users  account. It's work ok.

```
[WebMethod]
public string Login(string userName, string userPassword)
{
    if(Membership.ValidateUser(userName,userPassword))
    {
        return "Login succesfull";
    }
    return "Bad loginName or password";
}
```

The I add method on create user account.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void CreateUser(string userName, string userPassword, 
        string userEmail, string userQuestion, string userAnswer)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus status;
        try
        {
            Membership.CreateUser(userName, userPassword,
                        userEmail, userQuestion, userAnswer, true, out status);
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Problem is, if I call webmethod CreateUser user account is not created. The user data are not written into database. I don't get any exception when I call webmethod CreateUser, where can be problem? Anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try running a database profiler against your db to check if it is being hit and the sp's called.

Comment: please also provide the web.config entry for membership element

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow up your strong password rolls by default you have to use capital letters numbers and special character i.e.  use "PassW@rd22" Thanks, Hamid.